# Return full sentence when exact first word matches

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to return full text only when the first word matches my required word.
In this example, my word is "sparta"

```
"sparta where is fire" -> this should return me the whole sentence 
"Hey sparta where is fire" -> this should not return me anything as the sentence did not started with the Sparta
```

I am writing in python and got till this point:

```
text = "sparta where is fire"
my_regex = "^[sparta\s]+ [\w\s]+"
result = re.findall(my_regex, text)
```

This works pretty good when it finds the sentence. It returns the result as list with the text.My problem is when there is no match, result returns an empty list. Is there a way that when there is no match, I do not get anything. I don't need the empty string. Is there something else I can use instead of findall ?

Comment: Your regex is a bit off, it should be at least `my_regex = "^sparta\s.*"`. Why not `if s.startswith("sparta ")`? `re.findall` returns multiple results, you need one. Use `re.search` to get the first and only match in a string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My method will have an annotation of regex, when matched then the method will be executed. Example from https://github.com/lins05/slackbot
@respond_to('hi', re.IGNORECASE)
def hi(message):
    message.send('I can understand hi or HI!')

Comment: What's the difference between not getting anything and getting an empty list? You would still say `if not result:`

Comment: @PeterWood since I'm building the method as I wrote above, even when there is an empty list, my method will be executed. If there is no match, I want to skip my method execution.

Comment: I don't understand. How can you know there is no match? And your example doesn't have a list. You're not making sense. What execution do you want to skip? Why would you skip it? And if so, why not just skip it? You don't have to perform the search if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `match` function.

```py
text = "sparta where is fire"
my_regex = "^[sparta\s]+ [\w\s]+"
match = re.match(my_regex, text)
match.group() # returns "sparta where is fire"

match2 = re.match(my_regex, "Hello")
match2 # None
```

Comment: Your regex matches `rats are clever` but not `Sparta ? where is it?`

Comment: The poster is not asking about a correct regex according to his question. The poster is looking for an answer to "This works pretty good when it finds the sentence. It returns the result as list with the text.My problem is when there is no match, result returns an empty list. Is there a way that when there is no match, I do not get anything." @Toto